# How to use iterrows to correct a value in a data frame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a data frame that I've built from CSV files and pushed into plot visualizations. The issue is I noticed a couple of extreme outliers. 2 of the data sets I am working with are wind speeds and wind gusts. Basically, I want any value where the wind speed is greater than the gust value to be redefined as a gust.

I've looked into iterrows, and I think I'm close, I get a key value = 0 wen I try running my for loop, which I've read is due to the fact that I'm trying to loop through an indexed data frame. However, every fix I've seen hasn't worked. How can I go through each data frame by row and redefine the value to the other data frame if this condition holds true?

Here's my relevant code snippet:

```
 #Imports of data above this snippet

    #Create tables with monthly mean & max wind speeds
    #Ignore null values
    wind = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['wind_speed'])
    wind.dropna(how = 'any', inplace = True)
    wind['wind_speed'] = wind['wind_speed'].astype(str).astype(float)
    wind_m = wind.resample('M').mean()
    wind_max = wind.resample('M').max()

    #Limit to May-November
    wind_m = wind_m[wind_m.index.month.isin([5,6,7,8,9,10])]
    wind_max = wind_max[wind_max.index.month.isin([5,6,7,8,9,10])]

    #Build the same mean and max tables for wind gusts
    gust = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['wind_gust'])

    #Drop all rows that don't contain a gust (inplace)
    gust.dropna(how = 'any', inplace = True)
    #Convert data types from objects to datetime and float
    gust['wind_gust'] = gust['wind_gust'].astype(str).astype(float)
    gust_m = gust.resample('M').mean()
    gust_max = gust.resample('M').max()

    #Limit to May-November
    gust_m = gust_m[gust_m.index.month.isin([5,6,7,8,9,10])]
    gust_max = gust_max[gust_max.index.month.isin([5,6,7,8,9,10])]

    #Impose a catch that redefines any wind greater than the gust value as a gust
    i = 0
    for index, row in wind_max.iterrows():
        if wind_max[i] > gust_max[i]:
            gust_max[i] = wind_max[i]    # this is where I return the key error
        i += 1

   #Visualizations below this snippet
```

**EDIT: Visualization and data set example per request:

[image]

Note the outlier where the redline exceeds the blue line, which should never happen. If the red line exceeds the blue, it should be redefined as a gust (blue)

Data set example:

Columns: Station ID, Datetime, Wind speed, wind gust

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that `gust_max` and `win_max` have the same length ? And also did their indexes matches ?

Comment: @ChihebNexus yes their indices match and are the same length. They are monthly maximums taken over the same range, therefore they have the same number of bins. I verified that with .info(). It was 138 data points each it I recall correctly

Comment: do u mind sharing a sample of ur dataset, note where u want corrections to be made for the outliers, and post an expected output for the sample. that will allow folks on SO to give appropriate solutions not limited to iterrows